# Iterate through two lists with apply functions

Tags: r, list, lapply, mapply

I have a problem where I have a list of data frames where each column of the data frames has a name in the first row and x-s at some locations in the columns. If there is an x, then the name in the first row isviewed as selected. 
In the real world problem I read an xlsx file with many sheets where each sheet contains a large matrix: each column has a name in the first row and many x-s in a somewhat sparse matrix. Each sheet becomes a data frame in a list of data frames. The row names contain an identifier which is relevant to the lookup but not to my issue as described here.

```
data1 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("Mark", "x", "", "x", "", ""),
                    Col2 = c("Paul", "", "", "", "x", ""),
                    Col3 = c("Jane", "", "", "", "", ""),
                    Col4 = c("Mary", "x", "x", "x", "", ""),
                    Col5 = c("Peter", "x", "x", "x", "", ""),
                    stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data2 <- data.frame(Col1 = c("Mark", "x", "x", "", "", ""),
                    Col2 = c("Paul", "", "", "", "", ""),
                    Col3 = c("Jane", "", "", "", "", ""),
                    Col4 = c("Mary", "x", "", "x", "", ""),
                    Col5 = c("Peter", "x", "x", "", "", ""),
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

data <- list(data1 = data1, data2 = data2)
```

Each data frame in the list has the following structure (shown as a matrix for convenience) where the names are the same for each data frame in the list. Only the x-s are different:

```
> as.matrix(data1)
     Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5   
[1,] "Mark" "Paul" "Jane" "Mary" "Peter"
[2,] "x"    ""     ""     "x"    "x"    
[3,] ""     ""     ""     "x"    "x"    
[4,] "x"    ""     ""     "x"    "x"    
[5,] ""     "x"    ""     ""     ""     
[6,] ""     ""     ""     ""     ""
```

I would like to add one column ("Approvers") to each data frame in the list that is the concatenation of the names in row 1 if there is an 'x' in the column as follows:

```
     Col1   Col2   Col3   Col4   Col5    Approvers          
[1,] "Mark" "Paul" "Jane" "Mary" "Peter" ""                 
[2,] "x"    ""     ""     "x"    "x"     "Mark; Mary; Peter"
[3,] ""     ""     ""     "x"    "x"     "Mary; Peter"      
[4,] "x"    ""     ""     "x"    "x"     "Mark; Mary; Peter"
[5,] ""     "x"    ""     ""     ""      "Paul"             
[6,] ""     ""     ""     ""     ""      ""
```

At the moment I resolve this in two steps:

1. I create another list of lists that holds the column positions of each x
2. In a nested for loop I look up all the names in the first row and concatenate them.

The code is as follows:

```
position <- lapply(data, function(x) apply(x, 1, function(y) which(y %in% "x")))
position <- lapply(position, function(x) lapply(x, function(y) {if (length(y) == 0L) return(0) else return(y)})) # remove int(0) and replace with 0
position <- lapply(position, function(x) lapply(x, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))) # flatten second level list into string


for (i in 1:length(data)) {
  for (j in 1:nrow(data[[i]])) {
    if (as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(position[[i]][[j]], ",")))[[1]] == 0) {
      data[[i]][j, "Approvers"] <- ""
    } else {
      data[[i]][j, "Approvers"] <- paste(data[[i]][1, as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(position[[i]][[j]], ",")))], collapse = "; ")
    }
  }
}
```

To me this is clumsy and I would like to do this using lapply and mapply by looping through both lists simultaneously but I cannot figure out how to do this. Also, creating the position object and collapsing the column index of the x-s into a string and seperating them in the loop is overly complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative, it may be worthwhile to tidy this data, such that it is easier to manipulate and reason about. Also, the output that you want may not always be desirable given that it returns full rows of `NAs`. The code here, restructures your dataframes, so that column names become person names. It then reshapes the data so that there are two columns, the `name`, and the row index from the original dataframe (`row_ix`) where "x" appears for that name column. Then I drop the `NAs`, group by `row_ix` and paste the names together, returning tidier dataframes.

I appreciate that this a bit more involved, but storing the data in a tidier way may save you problems in the long run.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)
library(magrittr)

data %>% 
  map(function(x) #map function to all dataframes in list
  x %>% set_colnames(.[1, ]) %>% # set column names equal to first row values
  dmap(~ifelse(. == "x", seq_along(.), NA)) %>% # check for "x" in all rows of all columns
  gather(name, row_ix) %>% # reshape from wide to long, call new columns name and row_ix
  drop_na() %>% # drop NAs in the dataframe
  group_by(row_ix) %>% # group by row index
  summarise(approvers = paste0(name, collapse = ";")) # concatenate names from each group
  )

$data1
# A tibble: 4 × 2
  row_ix       approvers
   <int>           <chr>
1      2 Mark;Mary;Peter
2      3      Mary;Peter
3      4 Mark;Mary;Peter
4      5            Paul

$data2
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  row_ix       approvers
   <int>           <chr>
1      2 Mark;Mary;Peter
2      3      Mark;Peter
3      4            Mary
```

Comment: No problem, Paul. The reason I took this approach is because your desired output will contain redundant information - this may indeed suit your needs, but it is always helpful to consider alternatives :)

Answer (score 2):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` then with `apply` loop over the rows and `paste` the elements of first row together where the value is `x`:

```
res <- lapply(data, function(x) {
       x$Approvers <- apply(x, 1, FUN = function(y) paste(x[1,][y =="x"], collapse=";"))
       x})
res
#$data1
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  Col5       Approvers
#1 Mark Paul Jane Mary Peter                
#2    x              x     x Mark;Mary;Peter
#3                   x     x      Mary;Peter
#4    x              x     x Mark;Mary;Peter
#5         x                            Paul
#6                                          

#$data2
#  Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4  Col5       Approvers
#1 Mark Paul Jane Mary Peter                
#2    x              x     x Mark;Mary;Peter
#3    x                    x      Mark;Peter
#4                   x                  Mary
#5                                          
#6
```

NOTE: It seems like the `names` of the datasset should be `Mark', 'Paul' etc. instead of 'Col1', 'Col2',..

Comment: Very elegant. Thanks Akrun.

Comment: The nested apply function can be a tad slow as it will coerce the data frame to a matrix. Is there a way to avoid apply here (and not reintroduce a for loop)?